# How to sync contacts in one direction only -- from phone to Google?

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account

Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, Android 2.3.

I just lost a lot of time after syncing contacts -- executed from the phone. I assumed that all the changes will be transferred to Google account (as initially) but the effect was reversed -- my changes were deleted, and what I got was simply an undo function -- the old data from Google were transferred back to phone.

So how can I transfer contacts from phone to Google account -- I mean copy them only in this and only this direction?

*All my contacts are of google type, so when I say "from phone" it means they are stored at phone memory, but they are not "phone type contacts".*

Comment: Have the same issue. Whenever i make a change in my phone, google reverts it to that existing in its server. Thus I use a custom backup tool, like TB(Titanium Backup) and have disabled contact sync to google.